# Adding a parameter to a method call if it is not null

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm writing a wrapper class to AWS' SDK. This particular function has optional parameters (Filter, GroupBy, and NextPageToken). However, I can't default these to an empty list/dict or None in the arguments and have one function call with all optional and non-optional parameters, because AWS will throw an error when None/empty structures are passed in.

To solve this, I wrote case statements for each possible combination of optional parameters. Here's a sample:

```
if filter is None and group_by is None and next_page_token is None:
            return self.client.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={"Start": start_date, "End": end_date}, 
                Granularity=granularity, 
                Metrics=metrics)
        elif filter is not None and group_by is None and next_page_token is None:
            return self.client.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={"Start": start_date, "End": end_date}, 
                Granularity=granularity, 
                Filter=filter,
                Metrics=metrics)
        elif filter is None and group_by is not None and next_page_token is None:
            return self.client.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={"Start": start_date, "End": end_date}, 
                Granularity=granularity, 
                GroupBy=group_by,
                Metrics=metrics)
```

It's quite ugly, so I'm hoping someone has ideas. I tried unpacking lists, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem because the underlying function still has these optional parameters that need to default to something.

If python had a way to build a function call parameter by parameter and call it separately, that would seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you use **kwargs in your wrapper function and then pass in only those arguments that are needed for that call?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem myself a few weeks ago, and I solved it by creating a dict with the parameters, dynamically updating that `dict` based on certain conditions, and then passing it to the function call with the `**kwargs`  syntax (as @ChrisOram mentioned in his comment):

```py
params = {
    "TimePeriod": {"Start": start_date, "End": end_date},
    "Granularity": granularity,
    "Metrics": metrics,
}

if filter is not None:
    params["Filter"] = filter
if group_by is not None:
    params["GroupBy"] = group_by
# ...

return self.client.get_cost_and_usage(**params)
```